# How can I get objects from an array of specific objects?

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP-POO. I would like to retrive objects from an array and access to that object properties.

My intent code is:

```
require_once("../modelo/ClubDAO.php");
require_once("../modelo/Club.php");
require_once("../utils/ArrayList.php");

$clubs = new ArrayList();
/* GET ALL THE CLUBS OF THE DATABASE (WORKS GOOD)*/
$clubs = ClubDAO::get_instancia()->getAllClubs();

for($i = 0; $i < $clubs->size(); $i++)
{
    $club = new Club();
    $club->getNif(); /* HERE I CAN ACCESS TO THE FIELDS */
    $club = $clubs->item($i);

    $club->/*HERE I CAN'T ACCES TO THE FIELDS OF THE CLASS*/
}
```

ArrayList class is an encapsulation of a simple array, for me it's easier to work with, here the code:

```
class ArrayList {

    var $array;

    public function ArrayList() {
        $this->array = array();
    }

    public function addItem($item){
        $this->array[] = $item ;
    }

    public function toString(){
        $cadena = "";
        foreach ($this->array as $item) {
            $cadena .= $item;
        }
        return $cadena;
    }

    public function delete($item){
        unset($this->array[$item]);
    }

    public function item($item){
        return $this->array[$item];
    }

    public function size(){
        return count($this->array);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... is this code not working? Are you getting an error? Please let us know what you need help with.

Comment: You are setting `$clubs` to an `ArrayList` object, then you are throwing it away and *replacing* it with `getAllClubs()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting your variable:

```
$club = $clubs->item($i);
```

So it will not be the object you expect any more.